# Delete directory / App registrations Delete all App registrations No results

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have an error when trying to delete an ADD B2C. I do not have any application and it indicates to me at the moment of deleting that there one.

I already followed the following links:

blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureadb2c/2017/06/23/delete-b2c-tenant/

blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jeffgilb/2017/03/09/deleting-azure-active-directory/

stackoverflow.com/questions/43766171/cannot-delete-corrupted-b2c-application-and-tenant

Screenshots

[Image Portal Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9HpH.png)

[Image PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvYfH.png)

I hope you can help me out.

Thanks, regards.

Comment: Agreed that the azure portal is incredibly unintuitive.  I want to delete my test Azure AD Directory.  It says "Delete All App Registrations".  I click on the link, and it takes me to App Registrations blade.  Where it lists precisely Zero App Registrations.  Wha??

Answer (score 2):

In your Azure Portal screenshot, there is a link which says:

> To view and manage your registrations for converged applications, please visit the Microsoft Application Console.

Try going there to see if there are any converged applications registered in your tenant.

Additionally, you should try running the modern [AAD PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) rather than the MSOL PowerShell. The modern AAD PowerShell allows you to query for Application Objects like so:

```
Get-AzureADApplication -All $true
```

Note that Applications Objects are different than Service Principals, and it appears that both kinds of objects must be removed before you can delete your tenant.